# mysql_real_escape_string & slashes

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

Firstly magic quotes & runtime are disabled correctly in `php.ini`, and confirmed by `phpinfo()`.

```
PHP version: 5.3.4
MySQL version: 5.1.52
```

I'm only using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the data, after `htmlspecialchars` and a `trim`, that's all the data cleaning on the variable.

Yet, when I submit a single quote, the slash remains in the database.

When running `mysql_query` I'm using `"' . $var . '"`, although in the past this hasn't changed anything (could be due to the double quotes?).

Any ideas? and please don't tell me about PDO/prepared statements, I'm aware of them and I have my reasons for doing it this way.

Thanks!

Code example (this is the only thing done to the data):

```
mysql_real_escape_string( htmlspecialchars( trim( $data ) ) );
```

Comment: Can you show some example data and code?

Comment: To let you know, mysql_real_escape_string doesn't clean anything. It is not "cleaning" function at all. Go figure

Comment: Could you give a snippet of your code perhaps, makes it a lot easier to identify the problem.
@Col. Shrapnel: Well it escapes special characters, which could be said is a 'cleaning' process, guess that's matter of interpretation though

Comment: @Cyber it merely escapes delimiters. It's darn **escaping** function. that's all. As a consequence, this "cleaning" won't clean anything if you won't enclose your data in quotes. A number, for example.

Comment: @Fizzadar. You are running escatpig twice. in **your** code. Which is unknown to anyone here. So, it's **your** job to debug your code and find the place where it adds quotes second time. Clear enough?

Comment: @Col.Shapnel. No, I'm not. I've posted the code above, that's all that's happening to the data.

Comment: @Fizzadar: Can you also show the code you use to retrieve the data from the database and the code you use to display the result to the user?

Comment: That's not enough code. Also show the part where you handicraft the SQL query for insertion. I have a suspicion your usage of `"' . $var . '"` is not quite proper. You seemingly use single quotes for the PHP string, and use double quotes within the final SQL query. Should be the other way round.

Comment: @mario: Either can work in MySQL, though it depends on MySQL settings. *A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote or double quote characters* - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Comment: Fizzadar. 1. write **test** code. Which doing only adding to database and **nothing** selse. 2. Run it. 3. Post it here. Otherwise it's going to be endless useless blab. Go on

Comment: **AND print your friggin' query out!** Before sending it to the database. And see escaping with your eyes.

Comment: @MarkByers: Yes it works. However backslash-escaped single quotes are only unescaped if they are enclosed in single quotes themselves. If you backslash-escape a single quote within double quotes, then the SQL tokenizer has no reason to remove the backslash. This is most likely what's happening here.

Comment: @mario mysql tokenizer has nothing to do with quotes at all. What nonsense you are talking about? MRES just escape certain characters and it doesn't matter which quotes you are using to delimit strings.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel. The SQL tokenizer is what the whole escaping tohuwabohu is for. It separates commands from data. Not the parser, nor the storage engine cares about backslashes afterwards.

Comment: @mario still it will just remove slashes, no matter which quotes you are using. You are wrong and better test your hypotheses before publish them

Answer (score 3):

> I'm only use mysql_real_escape_string on the data, after htmlspecialchars and a trim, that's all the data cleaning on the variable.

No. **Only** use `mysql_real_escape_string` for storing data in the database. Don't mangle your data when you store it.

The function `htmlspecialchars` is used to encode a string to HTML (`<` becomes `&lt;` etc.) and it should only be used for this purpose.

Comment: That's a valid view, but not really an answer to his question, is it?

Comment: Then you have to remember to sanitize it with htmlentities, when you return it from the database and want to display the data on the front end...

Comment: @Pekka it IS an answer. If one is doing this way and have magic quotes off in real, they have not a single problem with slashes.

Comment: @Col well, finding that out is what this question is about, isn't it? He claims to have magic quites turned off.

Comment: Clearly it's not obvious, but magic_quotes is off. I'm only using htmlspecialchars before storing the data so I don't need to use it when displaying the data. At the end of the day, it makes no difference and has no affect on the question.

Comment: @Pekka well he's either wrong or doing escaping twice, It's matter of double-check anyway, and nothing else. Just double check. It's not some hidden feature of PHP or bug in mysql or well known pitfall. It's his code only

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the massively misguided, unhelpful and damaging option

```
magic_quotes_gpc
```

Has been enabled?

You can check that in the output of phpinfo(), but there's not a lot you can do if the server admin has enabled it globally without the ability to overrride.

I recommend checking if it's on (on every page of the app of course), and if so, causing the application to die quickly and painfully to ensure that you avoid data corruption (which chiefly manifests itself as the proliferation of backslashes you described).

Then go around to the server admin's house with a blunt weapon of your choice.

Hopefully you can do all this before your database becomes overrun with hoards of evil self-multiplying backslashes.

Comment: He claims to have it turned off.

Comment: It's off. I run the server, and it's definitely disabled, there's no way I'd allow that rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

your storing procedure is correct. (altough htmlspecialchars and/or trim is probably not needed - but i dunno about your application)

from the information you are providing there is no reason to be seen for your problem.

the next debugging approach would then be remembering whatever else you may changed or has been changed on your system (maby you are using some 3rd party installation image?).

if that fails ie is left to wild guessing possible causes, for which i will offer a first one:

mysql could be running in  [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) -mode, which would cause backlashes to be treated as regular characters.

furthermore it looks like you are wrapping your strings in double quotes, which would then insert a single quote - which usually gets escaped - straight into your database, preceded by a backslash.

it may very likely be also possible that - as you are wrapping your strings with double quotes inside your sql statements, which is not how it should be like and i am baffled you dont get a syntax violation error, you end up with some query like `"john\'s house"` which is caused by the single quote escaping from mysql_real_escape, which would be correct if you had your query correctly wrapped by single quotes.

which leads me to the question. do you get a syntax error (or an injected query) when trying to insert double quotes?

as for your comment. you could very well prepare statements with pdo and, then get the query string form it, and execute them using mysql functions. however i realise that this is no solution to your problem.

please also try putting your whole query in only one variable and print that out directly before executing it. then have a look at it and follow any wrong manipulation back operation by operation that is done to produce the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use double quotes *within* the SQL commands after escaping the data:

```
 SELECT "1\'2"
```

then it will store and return the value as `1\'2` with the backslash still intact.

The proper syntax for SQL strings is using single quotes. That's what `mysql_real_escape_string` is escaping for. Else it would have to escape double quotes, whose usage however it is completely unaware of.

Use double quotes in PHP. Use single quotes for SQL. Rewrite your code like that:

```
 $x = escapy($x);
 $y = escapy($y);
 sql_query("INSERT INTO tbl (x,y) VALUES ('$x', '$y')");
```

Comment: `SELECT "1\'2"` returns `1'2` for me - no backslash.

Comment: @MarkByers: Not tested with My. Just tried SQLite which exhibits this behaviour. And still seems most likely from his only code snippet.